# android header file for rtsp

Tags: android, rtsp, rtp

I plan to create **rtsp/rtp live video streaming** mobile to server but i create header package

```
import android.net.rtp; 
import android.net.RtpStream;
```

on android but this is show error  "`The import android.net.rtp cannot be resolved`".Any one can please help me,and give me sample `rtsp android` i follow that one.All ideas are welcome.Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

These packages available since ***API level 12***. 
You need to change `android:minSdkVersion` or `android:targetSdkVersion` property of `<uses-sdk>` field in manifest file to `12`.

Comment: Hi jamapag, Thanks for ur guidens... i implement on api level 12

Answer (score 0):

What API are you using in your project? It's probably the wrong level.

Comment: hi jjg, am currently using android 2.1 any thing wrong. all ideas are welcome.